# How to make case 2 remember what case 1 save in file?

Tags: c

i have make my own program.

case 1:

```
            Records[0] = fopen("Records.txt", "r+"); // read mode
            Records[1] = fopen("Records1.txt", "r+");
            Records[2] = fopen("Records2.txt", "r+");
            Records[3] = fopen("Records3.txt", "r+");
            Records[4] = fopen("Records4.txt", "r+");
            Records[5] = fopen("Records5.txt", "r+");
            Records[6] = fopen("Records6.txt", "r+");
            Records[7] = fopen("Records7.txt", "r+");
            Records[8] = fopen("Records8.txt", "r+");
            Records[9] = fopen("Records9.txt", "r+");
            Records[10] = fopen("Records10.txt", "r+");

        printf("\n\t\tEnter bus no: ");
        scanf("%d", &bus);  

        if(bus_inumber[bus]==0)
            {
            printf("\t\tEnter Driver's name: ");
        scanf("%s", name[bus]);
        printf("\t\tArrival time: ");
        scanf("%d", &arrival[bus]);
            printf("\t\tDeparture: ");
        scanf("%d", &departure[bus]);
         printf("\t\tFrom: ");
        scanf("%s", from[bus]);
        printf("\t\tTo: ");
        scanf("%s", to[bus]);
        input=1;
        bus_inumber[bus]=1;

        fprintf(Records[bus], "\nBus no:\t%d \nDriver:\t%s \tArrival Time:\t%d \tDeparture Time:\t%d \nFrom:\t%s\t \tTo:\t%s\n", bus, name[bus], arrival[bus], departure[bus], from[bus], to[bus]);
        fclose(Records[bus]);

            }
        else
        {
                        printf("\t\t\n\t\t||||||This bus number already registered by %s||||||\n", name[bus]); 

        }


        }break;
```

i use case 1(above) for save my bus into file .

case 2:

```
            Records[0] = fopen("Records.txt", "r"); // read mode
            Records[1] = fopen("Records1.txt", "r");
            Records[2] = fopen("Records2.txt", "r");
            Records[3] = fopen("Records3.txt", "r");
            Records[4] = fopen("Records4.txt", "r");
            Records[5] = fopen("Records5.txt", "r");
            Records[6] = fopen("Records6.txt", "r");
            Records[7] = fopen("Records7.txt", "r");
            Records[8] = fopen("Records8.txt", "r");
            Records[9] = fopen("Records9.txt", "r");
            Records[10] = fopen("Records10.txt", "r");

            Reservation[0] = fopen("Reservation.txt", "r+"); // read mode
            Reservation[1] = fopen("Reservation1.txt", "r+");
            Reservation[2] = fopen("Reservation2.txt", "r+");
            Reservation[3] = fopen("Reservation3.txt", "r+");
            Reservation[4] = fopen("Reservation4.txt", "r+");
            Reservation[5] = fopen("Reservation5.txt", "r+");
            Reservation[6] = fopen("Reservation6.txt", "r+");
            Reservation[7] = fopen("Reservation7.txt", "r+");
            Reservation[8] = fopen("Reservation8.txt", "r+");
            Reservation[9] = fopen("Reservation9.txt", "r+");
            Reservation[10] = fopen("Reservation10.txt", "r+");

        printf("\t\tBus no: ");
        scanf("%d", &bus);


        if(bus_inumber[bus]==1)
        {
        printf("\t\tSeat number: ");
        scanf("%d", &seat);
        while(bus_seat[bus][seat]==1)
                {
                    printf("\t\tThis seat number has already been registered\n\t\tPlease choose another seat number:");
                    scanf("%d", &seat);
                }
        bus_seat[bus][seat]=1;
        printf("\t\tEnter passenger's name: ");
        scanf("%s", pname[bus][seat]);

        for(seat=1;seat<31;seat++)
        fprintf(Reservation[bus], "\n%d \t%s" ,seat,pname[bus][seat]  );
        fclose(Reservation[bus]);           
        }

        else
        printf("\t\tSorry, this bus is not operating yet.\n\t\tPlease install the bus to register.\n");

        }break;
```

I use case 2(above) for do reservation for my seat in bus.

my problem is when i close the program and open it again, the case 2 cannot remember bus that i install early. whent i choose case 2 and choose bus no:1 it say that the bus is not operating yet. But before i choose case 2, I just install bus no:1. What have i to do now.?

Comment: `bus_inumber[bus]=1;` is local or global array right? so at each load of program it initial value will zero. you must store bus number in file also.

Comment: fprintf(Records[bus], "\nBus no:\t%d \nDriver:\t%s \tArrival Time:\t%d    \tDeparture Time:\t%d \nFrom:\t%s\t \tTo:\t%s\n", bus, name[bus], arrival[bus], departure[bus], from[bus], to[bus]);
fclose(Records[bus]); -------- i also make file for bus number ..

Comment: Please edit your question and format your code correctly, you will do us (and yourself) a favor.

Answer (score 0):

you probably not posted whole code here but looking some code here there is one array `bus_inumber[]` which might be local or global is might be the key factor for your issue.

Possible issue might be like as follows

During run state of your program you have set state 1 for bus number for which you enter the bus info,Now at reservation time you check that bus state if it set 1 then do reservation.So this logic works until your program loaded in RAM but it close and re-run then `bus_inumber[]` again initialized (probably with zero).

Now what you need here to save `bus_inumber[]` in some file  and on run program initialize this array with file data.

Also post more code so we can get idea.and it's not simple as you do so far for program might be related to `bus reservation system` or something else.it's require lots of validation and error checking mechanism.